# Get Height of Scrollable Context

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have been making a simple test app, where is only one button which will after press redirect you to Google Play store or any other app with scrollable context.

When we press such button placed in the test app, Google Play will apear. It means we have open two apps, our test app and GP. The test app will now run in background, because GP will be shown on display. And the question is, how can I get with the test app running in background information about the height of GP (or any other scrollable app)? Not just height of the display, but total height.

---

In this image it is shown, how it can look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvNSX.jpg

*Thanks in advance for any help.*

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the total height of foreground app's View.

That is not possible. Views are Java objects. The Views of another app are in that app's heap space in that app's process, not yours.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is not it also available to do in any other programming language?

Comment: You can write apps for android using the Android NDK ( I believe it supports C/C++) but you still wont get access to other app's heap space.. so sadly, no.